# How to fetch documents, and eForms from public folder mailbox

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

> Public folder content can include email messages, posts, documents,
>   and eForms. I want to fetch all the data available inside public
>   folder mailbox. I am able to fetch email messages and posts.

```
How to fetch documents and eForms for the public folder shared mailbox? Which property needs to be set in the soap payload
```

Comment: What code do you use now for fetching messages and posts from a public folder?

Comment: I am using outlook ews soap api's for the same.

Answer (score 0):

eForms get stored in the NON_IPM_Subtree see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/exota/how-to-create-publish-organizational-forms-in-exchange-2013office-365. AFAIK EWS won't let you enumerate those folders in a Public Folder Mailbox you maybe able to get the FolderId using the Exchange Management Shell cmdlets (Get-PublicFolder) and then connect to the folders using EWS. Otherwise you will need to use MAPI either via Outlook or a 3rd party library like redemption. I would suggest you first try a Mapi editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi and see if those folder exist in the NON_IPM_Subtree as they won't be their by default in an Office365 tenant.